# Adding an item to a json object using python

Tags: python, arrays, json, python-3.x, database

I have a simple json file containing user levels and experience, in this format:

```
{
    "users" : {
        "1" : [0, 1],
        "2" : [10, 2],
    }
}
```

The `users` object uses the user id as keys for the `[xp, level]` array values. I need to be able to write a new user to the file, such that later I can call it as `data["users"][id]`.

Here's my code so far, but it doesn't actually write to the file.

```py
import json

def create_user(id):
    with open("test.json") as file:
        data = json.load(file)
        temp = data["users"]  # get the users object.
        temp[str(id)] = [0, 0]
        # [0, 0] would be the default, until the user
        # gains levels and xp.

    print('user added to file.')
```

What can I do to make it add the user to the `users` object and save to the file? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
something = {
    "users" : {
        "1" : [0, 1],
        "2" : [10, 2],
    }
}
something["users"]["3"] = [-1,-2]
print(something)
```

```
{'users': {'1': [0, 1], '2': [10, 2], '3': [-1, -2]}}
```

if you want to keep it as json

```
something = json.dumps(something)
something = json.loads(something)
```

to dump everything to a file

```
with open(my_file_loaction, 'w') as json_file:
    json.dump(something, json_file)
```